# Sniff Packets using Charles Proxy and Visual Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, packet-sniffers, charles-proxy

I need to sniff packets that my node.js app is sending. I'm running **Visual Code 1.36.1**.

I in a corporate environment with all sorts of SSL proxies. I have Charles setup correctly, it sees Postman request. But requests made from my Visual code node.js app are not intercepted.

I'd be happy with a Charles set up or even a Visual Code menu.

The answers in [How to view network traffic in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41691099/how-to-view-network-traffic-in-visual-studio) don't seem to apply either because I'm on a Macintosh or because Visual Code has been updated since that question was answered.

Answer (score 2):

Adding environment variable

> NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0

fixed it.

Took this answer from here:
[Ignore invalid self-signed ssl certificate in node.js with https.request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888610/ignore-invalid-self-signed-ssl-certificate-in-node-js-with-https-request/11042814#11042814)