# Where's the Network Traffic Tool in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2019, network-traffic

According to this question ([How to view network traffic in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41691099/how-to-view-network-traffic-in-visual-studio)), in VS 2017, there was a network tool where you can see traffic.

I can't seem to find it on VS 2019. Has it been removed or moved to a different location?

I am using VS2019 Community Edition.

Answer (score 3):

[Answer on Github](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/visualstudio-docs/issues/4805#issuecomment-721431612) says the following:

> The version selector indicates it's VS 2017 only. There's a banner comment when you switch to the VS 2019 view. **This tool isn't available in VS 2019**.